# How to sort to post by votes in Laravel Queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

how can I sort posts by votes in Laravel Queries? I know how to get the count by using `->count()` but I don't know how to integrate it while joining other table.

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
                ->join('votes', 'votes.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
                ->select('posts.id', 'posts.description', 'posts.user_id', 'posts.created_at')
                ->where('posts.created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()-86400))
                ->paginate(10);
```

I don't know how to orderBy vote counts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're storing individual votes for each post (one to many):

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
                ->join('votes', 'votes.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
                ->select('posts.id', 'posts.description', 'posts.user_id', 'posts.created_at', DB::raw('COUNT(posts.id) AS total')
                ->where('posts.created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()-86400))
                ->groupBy('posts.id')
                ->orderBy(DB::raw('total'), 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);
```

Note that Laravel's paginate class is poorly implemented and, when used with a groupBy, might choke on large number of results.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But there's lacking with this. It is not showing posts with no votes. I want to make it from most number of votes to lowest or no votes.